# Exercise involving the Hewitt–Savage zero–one law

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

**Background**: Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of real random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ and let $X:=\bigotimes_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$ be the associated product random variable with values in $(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}},\mathcal{B}^{\mathbb{N}})$. An event $A\in \mathcal{B}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is called finitely permutable if

$$\{\tau X\in A\}=\{X \in A\}$$

for all finite permutations $\tau$ of $\mathbb{N}$. The zero-one law of Hewitt–Savage says that if $(X_n)$ is independent and identically distributed and  $A\in \mathcal{B}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is finitely permutable then

$$P\{X\in A\}=0 \text{ or } 1$$

**Exercise:** Let $(X_n)$ be an independent and identically distributed sequence of real random variables and let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that the only possible values for the probability $P\{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \in A_n \text{  i.o.} \}$ are $0$ and $1$. Also, show that for an appropriate sequence $(X_n)$ an event of the form $\{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \in A \text{  i.o.} \}$ with $A$ Borel is permutable, but generally not terminal.

For the first part I did the following:

For each $n$ let $f_n:(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}},\mathcal{B}^{\mathbb{N}})\to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ be the measurable function defined by $f_n\big((x_i)\big)=x_1+\dots+x_n$. Let $B$ be the event in $\mathcal{B}^{\mathbb{N}}$ defined by $B:=\{f_n \in A_n \text{  i.o.}\}$. Then $B$ is permutable because, since $f_n \circ \tau=f_n$ for all but finitely many $n$ whenever $\tau$ is a finite permutation,

$$ \{ X\in B\}=\{ f_n(X)\in A_n \text{  i.o.}\}=\{ f_n(\tau X)\in A_n \text{  i.o.}\}=\{ \tau X\in B\}$$

Hence the Hewitt–Savage law tells us that $P\{ X\in B\}=P\{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \in A_n \text{  i.o.} \}=0 \text{ or } 1$.

Am having trouble with the second part. Using the same reasoning I can show that the event $\{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \in A \text{  i.o.} \}$ is finitely permutable whenever $(X_n)$ is i.i.d., but I can't come up with a specific example where this event is not terminal.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I think it works if $X_i$ is Bernoulli and $A_n=\{0\}$.

Comment: @Mindlack In this case the event is $\{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i =0 \text{  i.o.} \}=\{ X_n=0 \text{ eventually} \}$. But why can't this be a tail event?

Comment: No, $X_1+\ldots+X_n \in A_n$ iff each $X_i,i \leq n$, is zero. The limsup of *this* is “each $X_n$ is zero” which isn’t a tail event.

Comment: @Mindlack Right the event is $\{(X_n)=0\}$, but I still don't see why this can't be a tail event.

Comment: It’s not in $\sigma(X_2,\ldots)$.

Comment: @Mindlack For if this set was in $\sigma(X_2,\ldots)$ then $\{X_1=1\}=\{(X_n)=0\}^{c} \cap \{ (X_n)_{n\geq 2} =0 \}$ would also be in $\sigma(X_2,\ldots)$. But $\{X_1=1\}$ lies in $\sigma(X_1)$, and $\sigma(X_1)$ and  $\sigma(X_2,\ldots)$ are independent, so we would have $P\{X_1=1\}=0 \text{ or } 1$. So we must choose $p\in (0,1)$ right?

Comment: @Mindlack And for the first part everything is OK?

Comment: Yes, I think it works.